# How to draw lines on an image by giving the end point and an angle with respect to the vertical axis in Python

Tags: python, image, draw, angle

I want to draw a line on an image. I have only to give the angle and the end point of the line. How can I do this with Python?

I think it is easy by identifying the vertical line passing through that given point and ploting the line according to the angle. The line should ends with the given point.

I tried it with this code. But didn't work.

```
import math

def get_coords(x, y, angle, imwidth, imheight):

    #img = cv2.imread('contours_none_image2.jpg', 1)

    x1_length = (x-imwidth) / math.cos(angle)
    y1_length = (y-imheight) / math.sin(angle)
    length = max(abs(x1_length), abs(y1_length))
    endx1 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    endy1 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    x2_length = (x-imwidth) / math.cos(angle+45)
    y2_length = (y-imheight) / math.sin(angle+45)
    length = max(abs(x2_length), abs(y2_length))
    endx2 = x + length * math.cos(math.radians(angle+45))
    endy2 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle+45))

    cv2.line(img, (int(endx1),int(endy1)), (int(endx2),int(endy2)), (0, 255, 255), 3)



    cv2.imshow("contours_none_image2.jpg", img)
    #cv2.imshow("contours_none_image2.jpg", result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return endx1, endy1, endx2, endy2
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way for finding the intersection point between the Y axis and the line is by using three cross products with homogeneous coordinates.

Ways for finding lines intersections are described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection).
The cross products solution using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) is described [here](http://robotics.stanford.edu/%7Ebirch/projective/node4.html).

Start by finding a very "far" origin point (x, y) - outside the image:

```
length = cv2.norm(np.array([imwidth, imheight])) # Apply maximum possible length: length = sqrt(imwidth**2 + imheight**2)
x0 = x - length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
y0 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))  # Reverse sings because y axis in image goes down
```

Finding intersection with the Y axis:

The Y axis may be described as a line from (0,0) to (0, imheight-1).
We may find the line representation in homogeneous coordinates using cross product:

```
p0 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
p1 = np.array([0, imheight-1, 1])
l0 = np.cross(p0, p1) # [-107,    0,    0]
```

In the same way we may find the representation of the line from (x0, y0) to (x, y):

```
p0 = np.array([x0, y0, 1])
p1 = np.array([x, y, 1])
l1 = np.cross(p0, p1)
```

Finding the intersection point using cross product between the lines, and "normalizing" the homogeneous coordinate:

```
p = np.cross(l0, l1)
p = p / p[2]
```

---

Code sample:

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((108, 192, 3), np.uint8)

x, y, angle = 150, 20, 80
imheight, imwidth = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

angle = 90 - angle  # Usualy the angle is relative to the horizontal axis - use 90 - angle for swaping axes

length = cv2.norm(np.array([imwidth, imheight])) # Apply maximum possible length: length = sqrt(imwidth**2 + imheight**2)
x0 = x - length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
y0 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))  # Reverse sings because y axis in image goes down

# http://robotics.stanford.edu/~birch/projective/node4.html
# Find lines in homogeneous coordinates (using cross product):
# l0 represents a line of Y axis.
p0 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
p1 = np.array([0, imheight-1, 1])
l0 = np.cross(p0, p1) # [-107,    0,    0]

# l1 represents 
p0 = np.array([x0, y0, 1])
p1 = np.array([x, y, 1])
l1 = np.cross(p0, p1)

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
# Lines intersection in homogeneous coordinates (using cross product):
p = np.cross(l0, l1)
p = p / p[2]

x0, y0 = p[0], p[1]

# Convert from homogeneous coordinate to euclidean coordinate (divide by last element).
cv2.line(img, (int(x0),int(y0)), (int(x),int(y)), (0, 255, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Sample output:
[image]

---

**More conventional solution:**

We may simply assign `x0` = `0`, and find `length`:

`x0 = x - length * cos(alpha)`
`y0 = y + length * sin(alpha)`

Assign x0 = 0:

`x - length * cos(alpha) = 0`

=> `x = length * cos(alpha)`

=> `length = x/cos(alpha)`

Code:

```
length = x / math.cos(math.radians(angle))  # We better verify that math.cos(math.radians(angle)) != 0

x0 = 0
y0 = y + length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))

cv2.line(img, (int(x0),int(y0)), (int(x),int(y)), (255, 0, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]